# Fixed header with Ink framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, ink.sapo.pt

I am trying to make my header with [the Ink framework](http://ink.sapo.pt/layout) (CSS/JS) fixed so it does not move on the page while scrolling and I can't seem to make it so.

HTML:

```
<div id="topbar">
    <nav class="ink-navigation ink-grid hide-all show-large">
        <ul class="menu horizontal flat blue">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu item<i class="icon-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Submenu item</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Submenu item</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="ink-navigation ink-grid hide-all show-medium show-small">
            <ul class="menu vertical flat blue">
                <li>
                    <a class="logoPlaceholder push-left" href="#" title="Site Title">Home</a>
                    <button class="toggle push-right" data-target="#topbar_menu" id="toggleVisibility">
                        <span class="icon-reorder"></span>
                    </button>
                </li>
           </ul>
           <ul class="menu vertical flat blue hide-all" id="topbar_menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu item</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu item</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="#">Menu item</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <a href="#">Menu item</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <a href="#">Menu item</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <a href="#">Menu item</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <a href="#">Menu item</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <a href="#">Menu item</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                      <a class="toggle" data-target=".submenu" href="#">Menu item<i class="icon-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="submenu hide-all dropdown">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Submenu item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Submenu item</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="border">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I've looked and tried toggling around with the CSS package but could not get it going.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe don’t format your links like that; it looks like spam. (And you’re not trying to spam… right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you using last version release or are you using the source from github?

In last version release we have a bug and it does not work if the element is wider than 90% of the viewport width.

Get the last build from https://github.com/sapo/Ink/tree/develop/dist and use:

```
<div id="topbar" data-offset-top="0" class="sticky" data-activate-in-layouts="large,medium,small"> 
....
```

attribute "data-activate-in-layouts" is optional to make it work in the selected viewport sizes.

Comment: Thank You, Im going to test it out tonight

Comment: @The---Doctor If this is the accepted answer, be sure to mark the answer as "accepted". This will help people coming here from Google searches.